# Undefined reference in installing a R package

Tags: r, g++, rcpp

I have a private R package,and when i try to install i get the error,where functInterp is the name of my package

```
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o functInterp.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o empTraceVariogram.o empTraceVariogramTemp.o -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/i386 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/i386 -lR empTraceVariogramTemp.o:empTraceVariogramTemp.cpp:(.text+0x180):undefined reference to  dnrm2_'
  empTraceVariogram.o:empTraceVariogram.cpp:(.text+0x5bb): undefined
  reference todnrm2_' empTraceVariogram.o:empTraceVariogram.cpp:(.text+0x5f8): undefined reference to `ddot_'
```

after the answer i got :

```
C:/Users/utente/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/RcppArmadillo/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:474:96: note: #pragma message: WARNING: use of OpenMP disabled; this compiler doesn't support OpenMP 3.0+
   #pragma message ("WARNING: use of OpenMP disabled; this compiler doesn't support OpenMP 3.0+")
                                                                                                ^
RcppExports.cpp:115:55: error: address of overloaded function with no contextual type information
     {"functInterp_empTraceCrossVariogram", (DL_FUNC) &functInterp_empTraceCrossVariogram, 8},
```

This is an error of RcppArmadillo or of the function?

Answer (score 0):

Your link instructions are wrong.  Look at any `src/Makevars.win` from, say, a package using RcppArmadillo and use this:

```
## optional
#CXX_STD = CXX11

PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) 
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

where there `$(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)` is optional for you, but Armadillo wants it these days.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i'm very in trouble,now i get this type of error ( i edited the question )

Comment: It's near impossible to help without additional information. You have an issue with your code, we don't see the code <shrugs>.